# Can placement of Google AdSense ads on a minority of pages with NSFW content get me banned?

Tags: google, google-adsense

Google AdSense's policy states that you shouldn't put ads on pages that contain NSFW content. I've noticed that if you do, they mostly identify this as NSFW and do not display the ad.

As there is no full-proof technical solution, and many UGC platforms, I assume many sites have an inappropriate page here-and-there and have encountered a similar situation.

If I have a small amount of pages that are NSFW (less than 10%), and the majority of the site isn't, can I be banned for placing the ad code there, or will Google just automatically not display ads there?

Comment: Just don't put ads on those pages. Problem solved.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat It's a dynamic site, very hard to identify UGC that is NSFW.

Answer (score 2):

Initially Google AdSense may not display ads on pages with NSFW content, however, they may disable your account as publisher complaints arise, especially for highly visited pages, which will impact your entire website, not just the pages with NSFW content.

There are reports of much less than 10% of NSFW pages resulting in disabled accounts, such as the one in [this](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/NxHIBxFouE4/OoC0sjmY4ZoJ) thread (with less than 1.7% NSFW content).

So it's risky to speculate what percentage of NSFW content pages will trigger your account to be disabled. It's wise to prevent this so that you won't have to file an appeal for them to consider re-enabling your account.

One thing you might consider doing is installing keyword filters, as covered in their guidelines here (among the other steps listed there): [What do I need to do to avoid having my account disabled?](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1217847?hl=en&topic=1342777&ctx=topic#q3)

> Install keywords filters (such as adult content, pay-to services,
>   hacking content, gambling content, etc.), especially on pages
>   containing user-generated content. Although we're unable to provide
>   information on topic such as "keyword filtering" or "content
>   filtering", you may wish to search for this information on Google.

Comment: Are you sure it's publishers complaints and not an automated check? Thx for the key-words filter tip, do you happen to know a multilingual library that is suited for that?

Comment: For sure they'd take action on publisher complaints. Disabling accounts based on automated checks not performed by a human seems questionable - that might trigger a warning though. Not aware of any multilingual libraries, but maybe a Google search as they suggest might turn up some :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can get banned for only having one NSFW page and it's happened to a lot of people, including me. So I suggest you not to place Adsense on pages that aren't verified regularly.

Comment: Did you get any warning and a chance to remove them?

Comment: No, I didn't, but I think that things have changed likely and you're more likely to get a warning now.